# python numpy concatenation automatically changing integer to double

Tags: python, concatenation

I am very new to programming and there is one curious thing when conducting numpy concatenation which I do not have much clue.

The code is simple, trying to rotate the array element by factor "k".

```
def rotate(nums, k: int) :
    a = nums[k * -1 : ]
    b =  nums[0 : len(nums) - k]
    c = np.concatenate((a, b))
    nums[:] = c
    for i  in nums :
        print(i,end='')
```

My purpose is to output rotated integer array.
It works perfect when array size is equal or bigger than 2.

```
ex1) rotate([1,2,3,4],1) ==> 4123
ex2) rotate([1,2,3,4],2) ==> 3412
```

But when there is only one element,
it suddenly changes integer input to double

```
rotate([1], 1) ==> 1.0
```

why is this happening?
I tried to search but couldn't find out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you don't have to use numpy at all, try to replace

```
c = np.concatenate((a, b))
```

with

```
c = a + b
```

and it will work like a charm. This is just the easier way of joining two lists.

Now, let's solve why there's double on the output. We can reduce the problem on passing an empty list to `np.concatenate(([1], []))` which is exactly the case of `rotate([1], 1)`. The problem is that `np.concatenate` [internally converts all the parameters](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy-concatenate) to `np.array`. Now, let's see, what's result of converting of an empty list to `np.array`:

```
  In [15]: numpy.array([[]])
  Out[15]: array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=float64)
```

`dtype` is `float64`, which means that even the other arguments must be internally converted to double/float.